# how multiprocesses/multithreads Ruby Web Servers work?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, process, webserver

the following code is a simulation of a web server that has 3 workers (processes) and for each new connection the selected worker creates a new thread. What I cannot understand is how a worker is selected to respond to a comming connection? and how all the three workers are listening to a similar port without a problem.

```
require 'socket'
require 'thread'

server = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0', 8080)
3.times do
 break unless fork
end

loop do
 connection = server.accept
 Thread.new do
        request = connection.gets

        connection.puts request
        connection.puts Process.pid.to_s # this will change with each request.
        connection.puts "status"
        connection.puts "Headers"
        connection.puts "Body"
        connection.close
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A TCP server listens to a port, waiting for a new connection request. When one comes, it creates a *dedicated socket* for the specific client (on another port), hands it off to a worker, and resumes listening to main port.

```
connection = server.accept
```

The above line is the line where a worker tells the server "I'm ready to receive a new socket", and the server will return the socket that it created for the latest client request.

If more than one worker is waiting for a new socket (all call `server.accept`) the server chooses *one of them* (it is not supposed to be important which one, but the obvious implementation is "first in first served"), and the rest simply wait for the next request...